# Where is the menu item ID?

Tags: menu, id

When on the 'Edit Menu Item', 'Details' page, I do not see the menu item ID. When I reference Joomla documentation it shows that it should be on the right side of the 'Details' page under 'Note'. There is no field below 'Note', and I am not seeing it located anywhere else. Joomla 3.4.0

Where can I find the Menu Item ID?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the documentations says, but the truth is that I haven't see the menu item id in the details page for a while, although it used to exist there ( I remember it in Joomla 2.5, below the template style field).

However, you can always find the item id of the menu item you are editing, from the url, at the browser's address bar.

The url will always contain the item id and it will be of the form:

```
index.php?option=com_menus&view=item&layout=edit&id=12
```

Note the ending of the url id=12.

Also, in the menu items list manager, you can find the item id of each menu item, at the right column with the ID label.

Comment: Ahh, the menu list manager did help, thanks. I was missing the bigger picture and looking only in one specific area.

I am still having trouble, although I do have the menu id now. The problem is getting access to hidden pages that I created on a hidden menu.

The following is what I'm doing:

Comment: 1. Created a Category
2. Created an Article and stored in the Category
3. Created a new Menu without linking to a module
4. Created a new Menu Item within the new menu; single Article option, and then selected the Article created in step 2.
 Got the link from this page which shows the URL and Article ID at the end. 
 
5. Got the ID from the Menu Manager (added &Itemid=xxx to the end of the URL)

Comment: In step 4, I should have been able to retrieve the hidden Article with the word 'Article' visible at the top. When I first did it, I was able to retrieve that page. Now I am not able to retrieve it.

In step 5, I added &Itemid=xxx (using mmy item ID in place of xxx), to the end of the URL thinking it would now link directly to the Article and associate with the specific menu id number. That didn't work either.

So, my question has changed and perhaps I should post a new question. But the question now is, how do I create a hidden menu with hidden articles? I seem to be derailing somewhere.

Comment: @DanMiller: Confusing - what the hidden articles are about? But yes, if you have other questions, better post them separately.

Comment: Got it figured out, thanks. And the hidden articles are simply to add in pages as part of the purchase process without having them on the Main Menu, or indexed in the search engines.

Comment: @DanMiller hidden pages can still be indexed by search engines.  I assume you've used the "Display in menu" option in the [Link Type] tab in menu options, to hide your menu item?  To prevent indexing, you should also set the "Robots" option on the [Metadata] tab, also in menu options.